# Bash File Transfer Issue Using SCP

Tags: bash, shell, rsync, scp, sshpass

I need to transfer files from machine 'A' to machine 'B' and I'm executing the command from machine from 'C'.

```
Run Command : 

$sshpass -p 'password_for_a' ssh -A -t a@x.x.x.x rsync -avz /home/test/* b@x.x.x.x:/home/test/
```

This prompts the "`Password`" for machine "B" which i do not want to type manually. I cannot install "sshpass" on machine "A" because i don't have authorization to install lib/packages.

Is there anyway to include the password using `rsync`/`scp` for the above command ?

I tried passing password using '`scp`' '`PreferredAuthentications`' too.

```
$sshpass -p 'password_for_a' ssh -A -t a@x.x.x.x scp -o PreferredAuthentications="password_for_b" /home/test/* b@x.x.x.x:/home/test/
```

I'm getting ,

```
Permission denied (publickey,password).
lost connection
```

If i am wrong anywhere , Please correct me ?

Comment: The server supports public key authentication. Your best bet is to set that up and not pass passwords around.

Comment: Since i don't wanna mess up during public key authentication on config files , I wanted to make it smooth using the above way. Need to look if there is no option then ! Thanks anyway

Comment: There is a password file option with rsync but only when an rsync daemon is running on the remote server.

Comment: Do you have `expect` installed? What does `which expect` say?

Comment: Do not write passwords in command line parameters. Command line parameters are public: `ps -ef`.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like `PreferredAuthentications="password_for_b"`. The authentication method is called `password`. If you specify something invalid, it obviously fails. Set up public key authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks All , I generated ssh-keygen and copied key files to (*.pub) respective machines. Now i can do password less authentications. Got clarify post discussions.